# Rxjs defer() but without re-creating the Observable upon subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

The [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) on `defer()` says:

> Creates an Observable that, on subscribe, calls an Observable factory to make an Observable **for each new Observer**.

How can I modify this behaviour such that an Observable is **created upon the first subscription only**, and then further subscriptions subscribe to this same one?

In my use case, the Observable factory I pass to `defer()` will create an Observable making a REST API call initially, and then  periodically repeats that call (a website which auto refreshes it's data periodically). So, I have an Angular template with several consumers, which subscribe to this Observable at different times, depending on which parts of the template are rendered, and when. I don't want each new subscription from the template to cause another API call because that's slow and wasteful, I want them all to consume the same auto-refreshing Observable.

Comment: Could you please add more details on what's your use case exactly, that requires this change?

Comment: @Amer: I updated the question with my use case

Comment: check my answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, there is no need to change the behavior of the `defer` function, and instead, you can use the [shareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) operator on the inner `Observable` to share the source and replay on subscription.

And here is an example of doing that with `defer` and `shareReplay`:

```js
import { of, defer } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpSub$ = of('Something!').pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('This will be called only once')),
  shareReplay()
);

const deferSub$ = defer(() => {
  console.log('This will be called each time you subscribe to the deferSub$ observable');
  return httpSub$;
});

// All the new subscribers will share the same source of the httpSub$ observable.
deferSub$.subscribe();
deferSub$.subscribe();
deferSub$.subscribe();
```

**Note:** In general, there is no need to use `defer` in this case, if you only need to return the same `Observable` each time without mapping its result to anything else, or merging it with another `Observable`... etc.

Comment: Defer isn't needed at all, as presumably the http request is also a cold observable

Comment: In general, yes, there is no need for it, however, I kept it in case he need to do anything with the `httpSub$` within `defer` on every subscribe, but without calling the HTTP request every time.

Comment: But, yes, I will update my answer to include this note. Thanks!